# doxygen c++ virtual functions and implementations

Tags: c++, documentation, virtual, doxygen

How do you comment with doxygen c++ virtual functions and the implementations

Is there a easy way to link from implementation to the "interface" or would you recommend to comment again every parameter in every implementation of the virtual function?

```
   class a
{
 public:

  /**
   * Cyclic read of data from Stack to host
   * @param address pointer to address object
   * @param data data to be transmitted
   * @param size size of data in bytes
   * @return transmitted number of bytes
   */
  virtual UINT32 DoSomething(ADDRESS *address, UINT_8 *data,
                                UINT32 size) = 0;
}

class b : public class a
{
  /**
   * Implementation of interface a - how to document? write everything again, or link somehow?
   * @param address pointer to address object
   * @param data data to be transmitted
   * @param size size of data in bytes
   * @return transmitted number of bytes
   */
  virtual UINT32 DoSomething(ADDRESS *address, UINT_8 *data,
                                UINT32 size) = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use markdown to format your code. If you make things easy to read, your chances of getting feedback increase.

Comment: ok thanks - first use - had to find out

Comment: please have a look at commands like `\includedoc`, \snippetdoc` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by my comment e.g.

```
class b : public class a
{
 public:

  /**
   * Implementation of interface a - how to document? write everything again, or link somehow?
   *
   * \copydoc a::DoSomething
   */
  virtual UINT32 DoSomething(ADDRESS *address, UINT_8 *data,
                                UINT32 size) = 0;
};
```

or with `\snippetdoc`:

```
class a
{
 public:

  /*
   [snip_a]
   Cyclic read of data from Stack to host
   @param address pointer to address object
   @param data data to be transmitted
   @param size size of data in bytes
   @return transmitted number of bytes
   [snip_a]
   */
  /**
   * \snippetdoc this snip_a
   */
  virtual UINT32 DoSomething(ADDRESS *address, UINT_8 *data,
                                UINT32 size) = 0;
};

class b : public class a
{
 public:

  /**
   * Implementation of interface a - how to document? write everything again, or link somehow?
   *
   * \snippetdoc this snip_a
   */
  virtual UINT32 DoSomething(ADDRESS *address, UINT_8 *data,
                                UINT32 size) = 0;
};
```

Note: the placement of the `[snip_a]` in a regular comment block! and the missing asterisks (`*`)

Comment: `\snippetdoc` is now obsolete. `\snippet{doc}` should be used instead.